# Can we have a pinned-messages feed?

Tags: feature-request, feed, chat-pins

It's nice that there's [a starred-messages Atom feed](//chat.stackexchange.com/feeds/rooms/starred/1) so I can keep abreast of [starred](//chat.stackexchange.com/faq#star) messages in my favorite SE chat room. But it's really the [*pinned*](//chat.stackexchange.com/faq#star) messages that are important to me. Can there be a pinned-messages feed also?